# Backslashes in my params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

***UPDATE:*** I have narrowed the problem down to the cucumber-rails gem doing something funky. It works up to version 0.4.1, but beyond that I get the below mentioned error. Still no idea why. I've done clean installs of the gem, to no avail.

I'm having trouble with my params including extraneous content.

A cucumber test submits a form, and there is a hidden field

```
<% if @collection.new_record? && current_user.pseuds.size > 1 %>
  <dt><%= label_tag "owner_pseuds[]", ts("Owner Pseud(s):") %></dt>
  <dd><%= select_tag "owner_pseuds[]", options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.pseuds, :id, :name, current_user.default_pseud), :multiple => true %></dd>
<% else %>
  <p><%= hidden_field_tag "owner_pseuds[]", [current_user.default_pseud.id] %></p>
<% end %>
```

When I use 'Rails.logger.debug it shows me that my owner_pseud ID is 5. However when the form gets POSTed, it shows up as below.

```
Started POST "/collections" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 05:01:57 +0100
  Processing by CollectionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "owner_pseuds"=>["[\"5\"]"], "collection"=>{"name"=>"collection1", ...
```

And I end up with:
    Couldn't find Pseud with ID=["5"] (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

I am using cucumber-rails (v. 1.3.1) and Capybara (v1.1.4).

This is the branch I'm working on: https://github.com/scottsds/otwarchive/compare/upgrade_capybara_1_1_4. Thanks for any help you can give!

default_pseud returns: #< Pseud:0x0000000a224070 >, which is correct.

Comment: What is `default_pseud` returning?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you specifying your pseud-id in brackets?  I think that's the problem, as Rails is trying to preserve the array-of-one-string format.

Try this, with the pseud-id *not* in brackets:

```
<p><%= hidden_field_tag "owner_pseuds[]", current_user.default_pseud.id %></p>
```

This assumes that default_pseud.id is not going to be an array, which, from looking at your code, I think is a correct assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting your [current_user.default_pseud.id] into an array. Try it without the brackets, like this:

```
<p><%= hidden_field_tag "owner_pseuds[]", current_user.default_pseud.id %></p>
```

and currrent_user.default_pseud.id will be evaluated as a string, which seems like what you want.

Comment: I still get the same error. I should note that this particular test (work_create.feature) passes on the master branch using older versions of cucumber-rails and capybara. I've made no changes to the actual feature itself, and following the backtrace (https://gist.github.com/scottsds/5b6774b3aa2c84cabe91) I see no errors. I also can't reproduce this error outside of the cucumber tests on a live copy of the application.

Comment: Change owner_pseuds[] to owner_pseuds, and your current_user.default_pseud.id will get passed as a string, instead of in an array container.

Comment: Unfortunately owner_pseuds has to be an array because there is a possibility that the user has more than one. Letting it be passed in as a string causes errors later in the create method when attempting to use .each on it.